# How to load image files with webpack file-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using **webpack** to manage a **reactjs** project. I want to load images in javascript by webpack `file-loader`. Below is the **webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
    react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js'),
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
};

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        jsx: './app/index.jsx',
    },
    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    watch: true,
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    relativeUrls: true,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.less'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {
            normalize_css: __dirname + '/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css',
        }
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            },
        ],
        loaders: [

            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?presets=es2015',
            },
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
            {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]"},
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader?presets=es2015']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
        }),
        new NpmInstallPlugin({
            save: true // --save
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        colors: true,
        contentBase: __dirname,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        port: 9091,
        progress: true,
        stats: {
            cached: false
        }
    }
}
```

I used this line to load image files and copy them to dist/public/icons directory and keep the same file name.

```
{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]"}
```

But I have two problems when using it. When I run `webpack` command, the image file was copied to **dist/public/icons/** directory as expected. However it was also copied to dist directory with this file name "df55075baa16f3827a57549950901e90.png".

Below is my project structure:
[image]

Another problem is that I used below code to import this image file but it is not showing on the browser. If I am using url 'public/icons/imageview_item_normal.png' on the img tag, it works fine. How to use the object imported from the image file?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import img from 'file!../../public/icons/imageview_item_normal.png'

export default class MainComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        download
        <img src={img}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

const styles = {
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the url-loader?

Comment: I removed the url-loader from webpack config file and remove the dist directory and rerun webpack command, the problem is still there. The file was generated.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

### Regarding problem #1

Once you have the file-loader configured in the webpack.config, whenever you use import/require it tests the path against all loaders, and in case there is a match it passes the contents through that loader. In your case, it matched

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
    loader: "file-loader?name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]"
}

// For newer versions of Webpack it should be
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '/public/icons/[name].[ext]'
    }
}
```

and therefore you see the image emitted to

```
dist/public/icons/imageview_item_normal.png
```

which is the wanted behavior.

The reason you are also getting the hash file name, is because you are adding an additional inline file-loader. You are importing the image as:

```
'file!../../public/icons/imageview_item_normal.png'.
```

Prefixing with `file!`, passes the file into the file-loader again, and this time it doesn't have the name configuration.

So your import should really just be:

```
import img from '../../public/icons/imageview_item_normal.png'
```

**Update**

As noted by @cgatian, if you actually want to use an inline file-loader, ignoring the webpack global configuration, you can prefix the import with two exclamation marks (!!):

```
import '!!file!../../public/icons/imageview_item_normal.png'.
```

### Regarding problem #2

After importing the png, the `img` variable only holds the path the file-loader "knows about", which is `public/icons/[name].[ext]` (aka `"file-loader? name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]"`). Your output dir "dist" is unknown.
You could solve this in two ways:

1. Run all your code under the "dist" folder
2. Add `publicPath` property to your output config, that points to your output directory (in your case ./dist).

Example:

```
output: {
  path: PATHS.build,
  filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  publicPath: PATHS.build
},
```

Comment: THIS IS THE ONLY DOCUMENT ON THE ENTIRE INTERNET that says "publicPath" will change the url used by the file loader.

Comment: if i use it like this `&name=/fonts/[name].[ext]` it ignores the `publicPath` and if i use it like this `&name=fonts/[name].[ext]` it tries to search for it inside the relative path, for example if a package uses this font resource and is inside a `vender` folder it will search in `[publicPath]/vendor/file` but the file is saved 1 level above the vendor folder. (i'm using url-loader by the way but giving it a low `limit` so it falls back to `file-loader`)

Comment: Just to add to the answer.  (please edit as I think this is useful) You if you find yourself in a situation where you want to bypass the webpack configuration on a require statement you can add two additional bangs before the import `require('!!file-loader!wenis.png');`

Comment: Documentation has been greatly improved since above claims :) - See: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#options and more info on publicPath: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#publicpath

Comment: `Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Query arguments on 'loader' has been removed in favor of the 'options' property (at ruleSet[1].rules[1].loader: file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext])`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Updated configuration for newer versions of webpack, thanks

Answer (score 24):

I had an issue uploading images to my React JS project. I was trying to use the file-loader to load the images; I was also using Babel-loader in my react.

I used the following settings in the webpack:

```
{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=app/images/[name].[ext]"},
```

This helped load my images, but the images loaded were kind of corrupted. Then after some research I came to know that file-loader has a bug of corrupting the images when babel-loader is installed.

Hence, to work around the issue I tried to use URL-loader which worked perfectly for me.

I updated my webpack with the following settings

```
{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "url-loader?name=app/images/[name].[ext]"},
```

I then used the following command to import the images

```
import img from 'app/images/GM_logo_2.jpg'
```

```
<div className="large-8 columns">

      <img  style={{ width: 300, height: 150 }} src={img} />
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Tried so much and read your comment to use url-loader. Many posts say to use file-loader, which kept giving me a 404 while using webpack and react. I used {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "url-loader"} in the webpack config.

Answer (score 12):

Install file loader first:

```
$ npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

And add this rule in webpack.config.js

```
           {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {}
                }]
            }
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can write the same like

```
{
    test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
    include: 'path of input image directory',
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'path of output image directory'
        }
    }
}
```

and then use simple import

`import varName from 'relative path';`

and in jsx write like
`<img src={varName} ..../>`

`....` are for other image attributes

Comment: This end part is very important for images inserted by jsx thanks @gaurav-paliwal.
using import imgPath helped me resolve it and the images were copied to the dist/build folder

Comment: That `outputPath` key helped me figuring out where to place files with subfolders and all that. The other answers here didn't work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

With the webpack5 you can use Asset Modules instead of file loader.

```
Asset Modules is a type of module that allows one to use asset files (fonts, icons, etc) without configuring additional loaders.Asset Modules type replaces by adding asset/resource emits a separate file and exports the URL. Previously achievable by using file-loader.

 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.png/,
       type: 'asset/resource'
     }
   ]
 },
```

For more information please visit the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/).

Answer (score 1):

webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
    },
}
```

anyfile.html

```
<img src={image_name.jpg} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example of our simple Vue component.

```
<template functional>
    <div v-html="require('!!html-loader!./../svg/logo.svg')"></div>
</template>
```