# Using webpack file-loader with Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm getting into Angular 2 and webpack and I'm a little confused about how to reference images using [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader). As far as I can tell, that you cannot directly put a `require()` in your html like this:

```
<img src="require('./abc.png')">
```

The only way I was able to get this to work was to create a class member and reference it the html.

my.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: require('./comp.template.html')
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private myImg: string = require('./abc.png');
}
```

html:

```
<img [src]="myImg">
```

Is this how you're expected to use file-loader with images?

Comment: Check here: [How to use webpack for image loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader)