# Add animated gifs to react web apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animated-gif

I'm trying to define a transition state for my react web application when I'm publishing data to backend.

I want to show an animated gif in my render method.

So I import the gif image (like this [image]https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif )

using a simple import

```
import logo from '../assets/load.gif'
```

and add it to my render

like:

```
<img src={logo} alt="loading..." />
```

but I get an error in my react-dev server terminal

unknown character

How to add animated gif's to a plain react SPA.

Comment: You can't import an image as Javascript code.  You need to use a URL.

Comment: If you're using Webpack, have you set up a rule which uses `file-loader` or `url-loader` for `.gif` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load image files with webpack file-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader)

Answer (score 37):

I had a version that used a URL however, it stopped working. I found a site that you can download the spinner as a GIF, then I put that .gif into my images folder. From there you can use:

```
import logo from '../assets/load.gif'
```

&

```
<img src={logo} alt="loading..." />
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `require('path')` method

The `require()` method fetches the images and converts it to data URI format [Read about Data URI here](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/convert-an-image-to-a-data-uri-with-your-browser)

```
<img src={require('../assets/load.gif')} alt="loading..." />
```

Comment: worked for me. but, I had to move the gif from an outside-of-src-folder location (my project's public/images folder) TO inside the src folder...  in my case, I just added it to the same folder as the file containing the component.

Answer (score 2):

```
import logo from './gifPath.gif'

<img src={logo} alt="loading..." />
```

I used this and worked for me as I downloaded the gif

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify the path

Try something like:

```
import load from './assets/load.gif'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71015465/type-staticimagedata-is-not-assignable-to-type-string) if you get this error in typescript. or nothing shows up in js

> 'StaticImageData' is not assignable to type 'string'