# How to load GIF file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, gif

[image]    import logo from '../images/dizer.co.gif';

```
{this.state.showLoader ? <img src={logo} alt="loading..." /> : null}
```

Initially I have used `CircularProgress` Component for `loader` when i was working with `CircularProgress` it is working. But when I tried with GIF I am unable to load GIF I am not facing any error also.

May I know how to load GIF file in react.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add animated gifs to react web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371716/add-animated-gifs-to-react-web-apps)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code but still few things I want to let you know. Check whether the log path is correct and check showLoader becomes true or not. These are the two things you need to check apart from it there is nothing else to look into your code

Comment: showloader is true. When i use CircularProgress Component It is working but when I use it is not working and Path also right.

Comment: @Think-Twice duplicate is same as my code also still not working.

Comment: Have you tried my inputs first? or share your full component code for better reception. You must be doing something wrong yourself then

Comment: no, I have edited the Question, path which i have given  is right but it is showing like above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180457/discussion-between-user9883888-and-think-twice).

Comment: can anyone let me know?