# Type 'StaticImageData' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm struggling with interfaces on my little learning NextJS and TypeScript project. I thought I had it sorted out but am dealing with an issue on my Header.tsx when it comes to my `src` prop on my `Header` component. I keep getting the following error messages

> Type 'StaticImageData' is not assignable to type 'string'. The
> expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & ILogo & { children?: ReactNode; }'

I'm still not full confident in understand children props and how to make them flow from parent to child which has made an error like this a bit frustrating.

I've gone ahead and posted toe code below and welcome and suggestions both to solve the immediate problem, and ways to mitigate this in the future.

**Header.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar";
import Logo from "../Logo";
import companyLogo from "../../../public/assets/images/logo.png";
import { ILogo } from "../../types/headerType";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container flex justify-between h-16 max-w-full bg-pink-400 h-100px">
      <Logo className="object-cover" src={companyLogo} />
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**Logo.tsx**

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { ILogo } from "../types/headerType";

const Logo: FunctionComponent<ILogo> = ({ src }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          <Image
            src={src}
            alt="Logo"
            className="object-cover cursor-pointer"
            height="100px"
            width="320px"
            layout="intrinsic"
          />
        </a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Logo;
```

**headerType.ts**

```
export interface ILogo {
  //   image: HTMLImageElement;
  src: string;
  className?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 35):

You can print in your console the result from importing your image. If you get something like [object object], then you need to ask for the specific src property in the object:

```
<Logo className="object-cover" src={companyLogo.src} />
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a local static image so you need to add it to the type, instead of

```
export interface ILogo {
  //   image: HTMLImageElement;
  src: string;
  className?: string;
}
```

You can have this

```
export interface ILogo {
  //   image: HTMLImageElement;
  src: string | StaticImageData;
  className?: string;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I did need to create a type declaration for StaticImageData though.. I simply put `type StaticImageData = { src: string; height: number; width: number; blurDataURL?: string; }` in the same TS file with the calling script. Then, I set my interface Props to handle it: `src?: string | StaticImageData`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, it is much easier to use:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar";
import Image from 'next/image';
import companyLogo from "../../../public/assets/images/logo.png";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container flex justify-between h-16 max-w-full bg-pink-400 h-100px">
      <Image className="object-cover" src={companyLogo} />
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you import StaticImageData interface from nextjs image and this will allow you to use static image as string.

```
import { StaticImageData } from 'next/image';

export interface ILogo {
  //   image: HTMLImageElement;
  src: string | StaticImageData;
  className?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you import an image in Next.js or any other assets that are handled by webpack what happened is instead of the actual asset you are importing a module that hold's information about the asset
basically you will get this kind of information

```js
   {
        src:"../some-path/company-logo.35345345.png",
         other properties
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

or use a template string
src={`${src}`} worked for me