# JHipster 4. How to access files in /content folder?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm trying to play sound from NavbarComponent:

```
audio = new Audio('../../../content/images/Ding-dong.mp3');
```

I can't get image as well:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = '../../../content/images/image.png';
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
...
}
```

I always get error in console:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/content/images/image.png 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:9000/content/images/Ding-dong.mp3 404 (Not Found)
```

No problem to get there from navbar.scss, like logo:

```
.logo-img {
            height: 45px;
            width: 70px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background: url("../../../content/images/image.png") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
        }
```

How can I access to these files from .ts file?

JHipster 4. Angular 5.

Comment: JHipster uses webpack file-loader, so you could use your assets like in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader. Alternatively, you could put them in a different folder and configure `CopyWebpackPlugin` in `webpack/webpack.common.js`

Answer (score 0):

Adding new folder to CopyWebpackPlugin doesn't work.
I figured out that path in .ts file must be:

```
audio = new Audio('/content/Ding-dong.mp3');
```

not:

```
audio = new Audio('../../../content/images/Ding-dong.mp3');
```

for Angular 5 version.

Folder /content referes to /target/www/content/ and file must be placed there manually.

But for AngularJS must be:

```
audio = new Audio('../../../content/images/Ding-dong.mp3');
```