# How to render images with webpack + react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am fairly new to react and webpack and I am getting this weird problem which I dont understand.

The problem:

[image]

When I inspect the image the above is what i see which obviously does not show my image. I am usuing file loader.

my structure:

[image]

webpack:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const bundlePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["env"], plugins: ["transform-class-properties"] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["eslint-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    publicPath: bundlePath,
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    port: 8080,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/dist",
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
};
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

import the image like so:

```
import headerImage from "../../../../public/images/MyImage.jpg"
```

render like so:

```
class Header extends Component {
    linkClick = event => {
      if (this.props.properties.movment.position.x > 0) event.preventDefault();
    };
    render() {
      return (

              <Navbar inverse fluid >

              <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
               <Image src={headerImage}/>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
              </Navbar.Header>

              <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav pullRight>
                <HeaderLinks linkClicked={this.linkClick} />
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>

              </Navbar>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you import the image in your react component ?

Comment: Yeah, post the piece of code how you are importing your image

Comment: please check edits

Comment: I think you should look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader , it seems that `file-loader` is using the `publicPath` property, it could be the solution to your problem

Comment: you can try with this output : `output: {
    publicPath: "/dist/", path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took some time but It would seem that I needed to increase the byte limit to get this to work.

I also changed the webpack confic to as suggester by @Olivier Boissé via the link

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
loader: "file-loader?name=/public/images/[name].[ext]",
options: {
  limit: 100000,
},
```

and also the following:

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var requireImages = require.context('../public/images', true, /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/);
```

You can plugin the above code in your index.js file to directly reference your images from anywhere in the application.

You can also go ahead and use `<Image src="./public/images/MyImage.jpg" />` in your Header file without having to import each image separately.

Edit: Please check the path and make sure it points to the images in the dist>public>images folder

Comment: I added this to my indes.js file but I do not undertsand how I should refrence it in my header component? can you give a more detailed explenation please

Comment: see edit. I used the wrong braces and that part got hidden.

Comment: Still doesnt work, the difference is that the url is now " ../../../../public/images/MyImage.jpg"

Comment: wait. I got confused between the webpack path and the original images path. Let me change that

Comment: var requireImages = require.context('../public/images', true, /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/);
<Image src="../../public/images/MyImage.jpg" />

Comment: I am waiting for your edit but I wonder if this makes the file loader unnecessary?
Also doesnt this increase the loading time since If i understand it correctly all images are fetched at once

Comment: It is an alternative to using file-loader. It pretty much has the same load time as file-loader for lesser number of images. But if you are storing images on the client server rather than on cloud storage, you are already risking higher load times.

Comment: I did make an edit to the comment. Just reference the path to public/images in the requireImages variable. Don't reference them from dist and you're good.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I tried running a mock and it worked just fine. Do you have a repo that I could look at?

Comment: Increased the limit of the file loader, see my answer below. Thanks for the attempt! thumbs up!