# Webpack : how to work with images in scss and extract to css files.....?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm trying to build simple website using webpack, all setting are fine, except **generated background image url** in css....

My folder structure:

dist/ 
   css/
      style.css
   images/
      img1.png
   js/
   index.html

src/ 
   scss/
      style.scss
   images/
      set1/
        img1.png
   js/
   index.html

**style.scss**

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('../images/set/car.png') no-repeat;                        
}
```

**style.css**

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('../images/car.png') no-repeat;                        
}
```

Problem is **images/set** folder in src not created in **dist** folder

my **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    plugin: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/plugin.js'),
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    rules: [
     {
       test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
       loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please solve this issue, i referred many article but i did not get any solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load image files with webpack file-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader)

Comment: @ksav, suppose **images** folder has two sub folder namely **set1** and **set2** 


 `{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader? 
    name=/images/set1/[name].[ext]"}`
i think above code not working right...?