# Clean way to import SVG to be used as favicon in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, favicon

Im wondering about the best way to import svg image to be used as favicon in react

i have following code, which works:

```
import { favicon } from './static/favicon'


<link href="${favicon}" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

But here, favicon icon is exported const from .ts file:

```
export const favicon = `
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...0Y/QTN1SKbITsFi0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
`;
```

I was wondering if i can somehow just use .svg file and export that to be used?

if i try to do:

```
import favicon2 from './static/favicon.svg'

<link href="${favicon2}" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

i will get `function%20SvgFavicon(props)%20%7B%20%20return%20/*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[` error in the console.

Comment: It would need a webpack-loader to support .svg files - see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader. Also if you are using CRA based setup - see if reading this section helps - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs/.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a customizable icon with this library

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons