# webpack file-loader duplicates files

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

I'm using webpack and it's [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) + [html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/) to emit files into my output directory. It works almost as expected, because it also duplicates those files.

Here is a part of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
   module: {
      rules: [
         { test: /\.html$/, use: ["html-loader"] },
         {
            test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
            use: {
               loader: "file-loader",
               options: {
                  name: "[name].[ext]",
                  outputPath: "img",
               },
            },
         },
      ],
   },
};
```

There is a small example of how my output directory looks like:

```
dist/
- img/
   - img1.png
   - img2.png
- ab0d12.png
- c3d612.png
- index.html
- bundle.js
```

The two images with hashed names are unwanted duplicates of those in `img/` directory. As you can see in the example above, I'm not even setting the name to be hashed and I also cannot open the duplicate files in any way.

I'm using some plugins like `HtmlWebpackPlugin` or `CleanWebpackPlugin`, but I believe they are not causing the problem.

**Versions:**

- webpack `5.28.0`
- file-loader `6.2.0`
- html-loader `2.1.2`

Comment: Can you show the .html or .js file where you're importing those images? Where are `img1.png` and `img2.png` stored before bundling?

Comment: @superhawk610 images are stored inside a ```img/``` dir inside the ```src/``` dir. I'm importing them using ```src``` attribute: ```<img src="./img/img1.png">```.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a long searching I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader) SO question that seemed very similar to mine, however, the cause of the file duplication were different.

In version 5, webpack introduced [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) as a replacement for `raw-loader`, `url-loader` and `file-loader` and which are now ran by default:

> Asset Modules is a type of module that allows one to use asset files (fonts, icons, etc) without configuring additional loaders.

Every time webpack started bundeling my project, `asset/resource` and `file-loader` were running at the same time and resulted into duplication.

Eventually, all I had to do to fix my problem was to remove the `file-loader` from the `webpack.config.js` file and set a `output.assetModuleFilename` to my desire output directory.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. Then I found yours. Thanks!

Comment: yes that's the right answer i faced the same issue thanks Bro

Comment: Thats's it. Thank you!

Comment: can you add ur webpack config for better understanding? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

webpack.prod.js (dev config does not need compress image)

```
...
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'assets/app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
        assetModuleFilename: 'img/[name][ext][query]' // dont use [hash] in name
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource"
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
            minimizerOptions: {
                plugins: [
                    ["mozjpeg", { quality: 60 }],
                    ["pngquant", { quality: [0.6, 0.8] }],
                ],
            },
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack5 use [Asset Modules type replaces all of these loaders](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/), and with [image-minimizer-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/) to compress images

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Config sample added @Mousam Singh

Answer (score 0):

Like @Daweed already explained, the files are processed twice:
Once by the file-loader and once by the asset module.

If for some reason you are not ready to migrate to asset modules, you can disable the asset module processing by adding

`type: 'javascript/auto'`

to the file-loader as mentioned in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/):

*[...] you might want to stop Asset Module from processing your assets again as that would result in asset duplication. This can be done by setting asset's module type to 'javascript/auto'.*