# html-loader is not getting correct img src path

Tags: javascript, webpack

(problem solved!)

I am trying to use `html-loader` and `file-loader` to pack my image source which is mentioned in `index.html` `img` tag `src` attribute.

But it's not working because the `img` tag `src` is not refering to the correct path.

Just want to know is there anything wrong within my config?

my `webpack` config:

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/index.js', './src/scss/main.scss'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].min.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'build'),

  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '/img/',
              pubicPath: '/img/'
            }
          }
        ],
      }


    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

./build  folder after run `webpack`

[image]

my `index.html`
(I also tried to change the img src attribute to "./img/women.jpg" or "/img/women.jpg" or "img/women.jpg", but nothing work but just make webpack compiling error..)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="./src/img/women.jpg" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

built `index.html` in `./build` folder
(so what is this `620b11833eb3b1be1f33.jpg`?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<script defer src="main.js"></script></head>

<body>
  <img src="620b11833eb3b1be1f33.jpg" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you encountered same problem as I did, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907267/webpack-file-loader-duplicates-files) is my SO question.

Comment: @Daweed  I tried your solution. and it did work on my img src, but it failed when compiling scss background-image url..

Comment: @Daweed But I guess you are right, It seems there is some config setting that I have to add for background-image url compiling.

Comment: Yes for sure, I wasn't using scss in my case.

Comment: @Daweed I tried to follow guide in here:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
and everything works like charm :DD.
Thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I guess the error is caused by the problem which is mentioned by @Daweed in the top comment.

I am using webpack 5 but didn't notice that file-loader/url-loader/raw-loader is deprecated now.

The solution is to uninstall file-loader/url-loader/raw-loader from dev-dependency(and remember also remove all related config setting.),and follow the guides [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/).

my config setting now(which solved all problems) is below:

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/index.js', './src/scss/main.scss'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].min.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'build'),

  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'img/[hash][ext]'
        }
      }


    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks there is a conflict between `file-loader` and `html-loader` plugins, thus it's generating corrupted assets.

However, `html-loader` will take care of loading all the images ([supported sources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader#sources)), we don't need additional plugin `file-loader` to have that support.

So you can try just by removing `file-loader` configuration

```
  {
    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: '/img/',
          pubicPath: '/img/'
        }
      }
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create a `public` folder in the root project folder and place your images there in the `img` folder (for example). I think that should work out of the box without any configuration. Then refer to image as `img/women.jpg`

Comment: should I remove any config setting ?
I tried tp create a public folder in root and changed the img src , but it just make the compile error  :(

Comment: I leave my github testing repo at the top , maybe you can try it.

Comment: @Mizok.H Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578665/push-assets-folder-to-public-directory-with-webpack) answer first? If don't work, I'll try to find the solution on my own.