# How to import images url inside a javascript file

Tags: javascript

So I copied a code in react to native javascript. I have a folder named `imgs` this folder contains all the images and an index.js file that looks like this.

```
export { default as img1 } from "./one.jpg";
export { default as img2 } from "./two.jpg";
export { default as img3 } from "./three.jpg";
export { default as img4 } from "./four.jpg";
export { default as img5 } from "./five.jpg";
```

Now I tried to import these images to another file like this

```
import { img1, img2, img3, img4, img5 } from "./imgs";
```

and I get an error in my console
[image]

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

this works like a charm when I used it in CRA but it doesn't work here. What am I missing

Comment: In React when importing an image webpack, or which bundler you are using, resolves the imported image to it's file path. So `<img src={img1}/>` becomes `<img src="/path/to/img">`, that results in the image being loaded by the browser as normal.

Comment: You cannot import images into a plain js file as describe above. So my question is, how do you want to use the images in the plain js project? Based on that one could give a fitting answer.

Comment: The file that I'm importing the image to was supposed to mimic an API response. I'm aware that react imports local images as URL and that's exactly what I needed. that URL will later be filled in `img`'s `src` parameter dynamically. So this is actually not needed if I have an actual API but I need it to mimic an API response with local images

Comment: In that case you could then store the file URLs as strings in another js file and then reference that js file to have access to the URLs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load image files with webpack file-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader)

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I create a file and put all the image calls in it

```
const image1=requre("../location image ")

export {
image1
}
```

And in the file where I want to use the pictures

```
import {image1} from  "../images file"

<Image source={image1} />
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the problem is related webpack configuration.